# paging in DataList Control in ASP.net?

Tags: paging, datalist

I want to use DataList Control but my data is very Great , I want to paging that but I can't.

how do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I know, the DataList control does not contain a built-in paging mechanism like the Gridview control, However there are a few ways round it.

I suggest you check out the following link:

http://www.dotnetjohn.com/articles.aspx?articleid=48

OR

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/DataListPaging.aspx